# SwiftUI NavigationLink - "lazy" destination? Or how to not code duplicate `label`?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12

(on macOS Big Sur with Xcode 12 beta)
One thing I've been struggling with in SwiftUI is navigating from e.g. a `SetUpGameView` which needs to create a `Game` struct depending on e.g. player name inputted by the user in this view and then proceed with navigation to `GameView` via a NavigationLink, being button-like, which should be disabled when `var game: Game?` is nil. The game cannot be initialized until all necessary data has been inputted by the user, but in my example below I just required `playerName: String` to be non empty.

#### I have a decent solution, but it seems too complicated.

Below I will present multiple solutions, all of which seems too complicated, I was hoping you could help me out coming up with an even simpler solution.

## Game struct

```swift
struct Game {
    let playerName: String
    init?(playerName: String) {
        guard !playerName.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }
        self.playerName = playerName
    }
}
```

## SetUpGameView

The naive (non-working) implementation is this:

```
struct SetUpGameView: View {
    // ....
    var game: Game? {
        Game(playerName: playerName)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // ...
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: GameView(game: game!),
                label: { Label("Start Game", systemImage: "play") }
            )
            .disabled(game == nil)
            
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, this **does not work**, because it crashes the app. It crashes the app because the expression: `GameView(game: game!)` as `destionation` in the NavigationLink initializer **does not evaluate lazily**, the `game!` evaluates early, and will be nil at first thus force unwrapping it causes a crash. This is really confusing for me... It feels just... wrong! Because it will not be used until said navigation is used, and using this particular initializer will not result in the destination being used until the NavigationLink is clicked. So we have to handle this with an `if let`, but now it gets a bit more complicated. I want the NavigationLink label to look the same, except for disabled/enabled rendering, for both states game nil/non nil. This causes code duplication. Or at least I have not come up with any better solution than the ones I present below. Below is two different solutions and a third improved (refactored into custom View `ConditionalNavigationLink` View) version of the second one...

```swift
struct SetUpGameView: View {
    
    @State private var playerName = ""
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var game: Game? {
        Game(playerName: playerName)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Player name", text: $playerName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }

                // All these three solution work
                
                //       navToGameSolution1
                //       navToGameSolution2
                navToGameSolution2Refactored
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Solutions

    // N.B. this helper view is only needed by solution1 to avoid duplication in if else, but also used in solution2 for convenience. If solution2 is used this code could be extracted to only occur inline with solution2.
    var startGameLabel: some View {
        // Bug with new View type `Label` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556361/swiftui-label-text-and-image-vertically-misaligned
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "play")
            Text("Start Game")
        }
    }
    
    var navToGameSolution1: some View {
        Group { // N.B. this wrapping `Group` is only here, if if let was inline in the `body` it could have been removed...
            if let game = game {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: GameView(game: game),
                    label: { startGameLabel }
                )
            } else {
                startGameLabel
            }
        }
    }
    
    var navToGameSolution2: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: game.map { AnyView(GameView(game: $0)) } ?? AnyView(EmptyView()),
            label: { startGameLabel }
        ).disabled(game == nil)
    }
    
    var navToGameSolution2Refactored: some View {
        NavigatableIfModelPresent(model: game) {
            startGameLabel
        } destination: {
            GameView(game: $0)
        }
    }
}
```

## NavigatableIfModelPresent

Same solution as `navToGameSolution2` but refactored, so that we do not need to repeat the label, or construct multiple `AnyView`...

```swift
struct NavigatableIfModelPresent<Model, Label, Destination>: View where Label: View, Destination: View {
    
    let model: Model?
    let label: () -> Label
    let destination: (Model) -> Destination
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: model.map { AnyView(destination($0)) } ?? AnyView(EmptyView()),
            label: label
        ).disabled(model == nil)
    }
}
```

Feels like I'm missing something here... I don't want to automatically navigate when game becomes non-nil and I don't want the `NavigationLink` to be enabled until game is non nil.

Comment: Similar question on Apple Dev Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650835?page=1#616787022

Comment: You seem to have a working solution and your question is about making it simpler. "Simpler" is probably going to be subjective and opinion-based, unless you specify exactly the issue that you want to avoid with your current solution - i.e. along which dimension you feel you'd need to simplify

Comment: I am asking for a no eager Navigation solution, feels like there ought to be one?

Comment: By eager, do you mean that you don't want to evaluate the destination view until you click to navigate? That's just not how SwiftUI View works. The `body` property is evaluated when the view is being added to the view hierarchy. To construct a `NavigationLink` view, it needs to have some `View` as its destination

Comment: @Sajjon I feel like you could use a `@Binding` here. Instead of `GameView(game: game!)`, you could pass in a binding for `@State private var game: Game?` as `GameView(game: $game)`. This means that whatever `GameView` needs to do, by that point `game` will have been updated to have the correct value.

Comment: @NewDev well if you have logical branching, SwiftUI does not construct the false statement scope views... which is what I’ve done in my solutions. And also, the `destination` View is not rendered in the body, the `label` is! So feels like it is just wrong that the destination is created eagerly

Comment: @George_E nah that will result in terrible code in GameView and is just semantically incorrect. Can you view Game that doesn’t exist? It would mean lots of unnecessary if let, or terrible force unwraps in GameView.

Comment: @Sajjon I'll add an example

Answer (score 2):

You could try use `@Binding` instead to keep track of your `Game`. This will mean that whenever you navigate to `GameView`, you have the latest `Game` as it is set through the `@Binding` and not through the initializer.

I have made a simplified version to show the concept:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var playerName = ""
    @State private var game: Game?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    TextField("Player Name", text: $playerName) {
                        setGame()
                    }
                }
                
                NavigationLink("Go to Game", destination: GameView(game: $game))
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func setGame() {
        game = Game(title: "Some title", playerName: playerName)
    }
}



struct Game {
    let title: String
    let playerName: String
}



struct GameView: View {
    
    @Binding var game: Game!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(game.title)
            Text(game.playerName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IUO should be avoided at all times

Comment: @Sajjon I don't know what IUO means

Comment: @Sajjon Did you also downvote my answer, when I'm trying to help you? This seemed like a sensible solution to me and for the information you have given. If this is not what you wanted, you could leave a comment specifying more information instead.

Comment: IOU is a common abbreviation for "Implicitly Unwrapped Optional", which is what you are using now in GameView, `@Binding var game: Game!` this opens up for unsafe code. It is a not as good and generally regarded lazy version of using a true Optional, which results in safe code. So yes I think this is not a good solution, hence downvote. Appreciate the effort though!

Comment: @Sajjon Oh it's implicitly unwrapped optionals - why is that a problem here? You could set a default `Game` if there has been no input, or disable the button until there is a player name set. Then you can guarantee that `game` is not `nil`. IUO is not a problem if you are sure you won't run into problems (as a disabled button would make us *certain* that `game` is not `nil`.