# SwiftUI: TabBarItems misaligned

Tags: swiftui

For some reason, tabBarItems are not aligned horizontally.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            CodesView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Codes", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill")
                }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) //Prevent split view on both Codes and Settings

    }
}
```

**Screenshots:**

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this in a similar question too... it's probably a bug

Comment: Try like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556825/12299030