# Resize label Image SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a label with a custom Image. I want to make the Image resizable, but I can't find  any way to do this. Here is my code ;

```
Label("Continue with Google", image: "googleLogo")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.red)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use custom label style, as for example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556825/12299030, and do with `configuration.icon` whatever needed.

Comment: Yup I agree with @Asperi, or you can create a HStack that has the Image() and Text() together, will give you the same result I believe and you will have the freedom of changing the image size as you want or the text() alone.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make the image scale solely, but you can use `.scaleEffect()` to make it bigger as a whole.

Answer (score 12):

You can write like this:

```swift
Label {
    Text("Continue with Google")
} icon: {
    Image("googleLogo")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
}
```

Hope it can help you.